# MediaElement not playing online .mp3 file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I'm trying to play an MP3 file from an online resource as bellow in WPF, but the app is just played without any error and also no audio. The point is that I'm able to play an MP4 file the same wave...
Any help is appreciated in advance.

```html
        public wpfVideo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mediaElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
            mediaElement1.Source =
                new Uri(@"https://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/2/13649_1459784562.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);

        }
```

```html
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement1"  LoadedBehavior="Manual" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Comment: Any idea about this problem?

Comment: To clarify, are you able to play MP4 streams or not? I am experiencing a similar issue, streaming mp4 videos work fine but I get a null reference exception when trying to stream an MP3 file.